# KDB: Joining column onto another column from a nested list of tables

Tags: kdb

I have the below table:

```
t:flip (`tabList`deskName)!((flip (`deskID`bType`ext)!(enlist 653j;enlist `ALL;enlist `30);flip (`deskID`bType`ext)!(592j, 594j, 601j, 603j;`ALL`ALL`ALL`ALL;`40`50`60`70));(`D1;`D2))
```

Trying to extract the `deskID` from a nested list of tables and join it to its corresponding `deskName`.

`deskID` counts vary in each nested table.

Desired result below:

```
flip (`deskID`deskName)!(653j, 592j, 594j, 601j, 603j;`D1`D2`D2`D2`D2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
ungroup select deskID:{x`deskID}each tabList,deskName from t
```

Comment: The query might be slightly improved as ```ungroup select deskID: tabList@\:`deskID, deskName from t```